# getting option tag text in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Can someone help me get the text of my option tag because i always get blank when i do.

here is the html/php

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="sel1" id = "type_set">Webhook Type:</label>
    <select name="type" id = "selecting">
        <option value="" selected disabled hidden >Choose Tagging</option>
        <?php

        $disp = PDODatabase::Instance()->QueryAll("SELECT * FROM social_media" );

        foreach($disp as $data){
            if($data['_DELETED'] != 1){
                echo "<option data-med='".$data['SOCIAL_NAME']."'  id = 'soc' value='".$data['ID']."'>".$data['SOCIAL_NAME']."</option>";
            }
        }

    ?>
    </select>

</div>
```

here is the script:

```
jQuery(document).on('click','#soc', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var med = $('#selecting:selected').text();
  alert(med);
  // var tod = ""+year+""+month+""+dat+""+ran+""+med+"";
  // document.getElementById("wname_set").value = tod;

});
```

thank you T_T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#selecting` is the ID of the `<select>`, you need to select the selected option.

```
var med = $('#selecting option:selected').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
$('#selecting option:selected').text();
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the value then go with this one :

```
var med = $("#selecting option:selected").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

console$('#selecting option:selected').text())